# Error while compiling Python script into .exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to compile a python script to .exe from the Python library `pyinstaller`. However, i got an error, as shown below:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)
```

I'm fairly sure its not an error with my file, what can i do to fix this? I'm trying to compile this to an .exe in the first place because it is my math project and i want anyone to be able to play it. My code: http://www.github.com/averwhy/UltraCoin

EDIT: Full error: https://pastebin.com/VVrUBGNn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its an issue with pyinstaller.

run

`pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.tar.gz`

source:
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4265

Comment: This worked. I see a lot of folders created- do i need all of these?

Comment: Folders after you ran pyinstaller successfully? I'm not sure, move the exe to another directory and run it, if it works you don't need those folders :)